# how can i select max date per month in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

how can i select the max date per month in bigquery? i have an column of dates, but i would only like to select rows which are the max date per month for a given month .

i have tried :

```
maxdates as (

SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CAST(payment_date AS DATE), MONTH) as month, max(payment_date)
 from adding_remaining
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(CAST(payment_date AS DATE), MONTH), payment_date )
```

but it does not give me what i want. this seems fairly simple and am new to bigquery so any help would be appreciated.

i only want the dates highlighted below, how can i exract these? i.e. the max date per month

[image]

Comment: i mean i have a column of dates

Comment: . . Your query looks correct.  What is the problem?  If you have a column of dates, why are you converting the value to a `date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider removing `payment_date` from `GROUP BY`:

```
maxdates as (
    SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CAST(payment_date AS DATE), MONTH) as month, max(payment_date)
    FROM adding_remaining
    GROUP BY month
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want the last day of the month, you can use [`LAST_DAY()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions):

```
select ar.*
from adding_remaining ar
where ar.payment_date = last_day(ar.payment_date, month);
```

Note:  This is the *calendar* last day of the month, not the last day in the data -- which your query returns.

Comment: but this is only gving me last day of the month, e.g. what if my max date for july is 28th then i would miss this row of data out